# React native vscode extension not working after few minutes

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-native-tools

Vscode react native extensions stopped after few minutes like import relative path suggestions ,go to definition, style suggestion, constant redirect.

I already tried to reinstall all the react native extensions.
this issue occurs only one project not other react native projects. so i assume its occurs because some code in this project

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.5",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "git+https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal.git",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-otp-inputs": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "0.0.11",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.0.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.5.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

.eslintrc

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier'],
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': 0,
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
    'global-require': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'react/jsx-one-expression-per-line': 'off',
    'no-tabs': 0,
    'no-param-reassign': 0,
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        singleQuote: true
      }
    ],
    'no-useless-escape': 0,
    'no-nested-ternary': 0,
    'react/no-access-state-in-setstate': 0,
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'react/jsx-indent': 0,
    'react/jsx-indent-props': 0,
    'react/jsx-wrap-multilines': 0,
    'react/jsx-indent-props': 0,
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 0,
    'import/no-named-default': 0
  },
  env: {
    jest: true
  }
};
```

Wants to show the javascript, react native suggestions like import lifecycle, style suggestions, import suggestions